# How to deal with "invalid reference format"

Tags: docker

I'm trying to pull a Docker image from GitLab based on commit but Docker throws an error:

`Error parsing reference: "test-driven-users:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format`

This is what I'm running:

```
docker build https://gitlab.com/coding_hedgehog/tdd.git#staging:services/users -t test-driven-users:jefso89472jf -f Dockerfile-prod
```

Where is my syntax off ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by fixing the commit part of the parameter in `-t test-driven-users:jefso89472jf`. The commit argument wasn't passed correctly from Dockerfile.